# Orientation of array objects along a helix path

Tags: modifiers

[image]I made an array of cylinders following a helix (which is going round three cylinders). The cylinders are parented to a plane to avoid distortion, this is my result - how do I manage to fix the orientation of each cylinder to make it orthogonal (to path)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Twist method set to Z up on the helix curve:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get exactly what  I want in my file by this method. The z- and the y-axis of the cylinders should be orthogonal to the tangent to the path (which is the x-axis).

Comment: In the capture above the plane array is orthogonal to Y axis (orthogonal in edit mode).